# This is merge sort program. I am getting confused in logic at mergesort function

Tags: data-structures

This is the merge sort program. I am getting confused in logic at mergesort function where low = 0 and high = 6
in the if statement. if(0<6) then go inside it and mid = (0+6)/2= 3;
then it's again calling mergesort fucntion with giving the value to the low=0 and mid=3; than mergesort will call giving the value to low=0 and high =3; and again this will calls continously and hit the last when 0<1 and then the statement will never gets false Am I right please help me.

#include <stdio.h>

```
void printArray(int *A, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void merge(int A[], int mid, int low, int high)
{
    int i, j, k, B[100];
    i = low;
    j = mid + 1;
    k = low;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (A[i] < A[j])
        {
            B[k] = A[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            B[k] = A[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    {
        B[k] = A[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j <= high)
    {
        B[k] = A[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        A[i] = B[i];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int A[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low < high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        mergeSort(A, low, mid);
        mergeSort(A, mid + 1, high);
        merge(A, mid, low, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // int A[] = {9, 14, 4, 8, 7, 5, 6};
    int A[] = {9, 1, 4, 14, 4, 15, 6};
    int n = 7;
    printArray(A, n);
    mergeSort(A, 0, 6);

    printArray(A, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, when mid is 3, high on the first recursive call will be 3, low on the second recursive call will be 4. On the next level for the first call, mid will then be 1 ((0+3)/2), which will be the new high in the recursive call. So at the next level down both low and high will be zero.

Comment: Thanks man it was very easy question. I was solving data structures for the very very first time and got confused in recursive call in this merge sort program. I was doing division there on the last level was (0+1)/2 = 1 my logic was this got confused by modular operator (0+1)%2=1 but  after after re-checking it 4-5 times it solved easily and yes it's feeling like I am pro in DSA it's not  truth but I solved most of the question  on my own logic. @500-InternalServerError